# Macro populates wrong values - current date

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to ask for a help. My Macro was about to populate the current date to all populated rows. At the begining it seemed to work and suddenly it started to change (overwrite) the header to the current date and put the current date in 1 cell below. Could anyone help me what should I amend to make it work properly?

Here is the macro code (reformatted):

```
Sub DateVerified()

    Sheets("Data").Activate
    Dim rngAddress As Range
    Set rngAddress = Range("A1:ZZ1").Find("Verified Date").Offset(1, 0)
    rngAddress.Select

    Dim ac As Integer
    Dim lastr As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet


    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    ac = ActiveCell.Column
    lastr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, ac).End(xlUp).Row
    Range(Cells(2, ac), Cells(lastr, ac)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.Formula = "=TEXT(Now(),""dd/mm/yyyy"")"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *might* suit:

```
Sub DateVerified()
    Dim rngAddress As Range
    Dim ac As Integer
    Dim lastr As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Sheets("Data").Activate
    Set rngAddress = Range("A1:ZZ1").Find("Verified Date").Offset(1, 0)
    rngAddress.Select
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    lastr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    ac = ActiveCell.Column
    Range(Cells(2, ac), Cells(lastr, ac)).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Selection.Formula = "=TEXT(Now(),""dd/mm/yyyy"")"
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

Comment: Hmmm that's really strange. I put your code yesterday and it used to work. Today I added a new macro to the spreadsheet (not related to your code) and then it started to do the same error like before (Verified date header changed to current date and one cell below it populated to the current date). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is likely to be going wrong on the line below:

```
lastr = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, ac).End(xlUp).Row
```

This attempts to go to the final row of the spreadsheet for the active column and then do the equivalent of ctrl+up in excel to find the last row populated in that column. To test this theory add a line of code directly after this:

```
debug.print "lastr set to " & lastr
```

and see what this value is set to looking at the immediate window (use Ctrl+G to open from the VBA editor).